# Let $ f : X \to Y $ a biyective funtion and uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $ f : X \to Y $  a biyective funtion and Uniformly continuous.Prove that is Y is complete and $f^{-1}$ is continuous, then  X is complete.

Comment: What have you tried? Can we drop the _uniformly_ condition from this question?

Comment: I have only applied definition for Uniformly continuous. and biyective funtion Also I´m trying to see what it´s for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Take a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ in X.

(2) $(f(x_n))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ will be Cauchy (why?).

(3) $(f(x_n))_{n\in\Bbb N}$ will be convergent (why?).

(4) $(x_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ will be convergent (why?).

Comment: Friends thank with your help I could do it.